# Can we call a person who loses things a "loser"?

Tags: nouns, semantics, morphology

> Think > Thinker
>     Draw > Drawer

Can we call a person who loses thing a *loser*?
Of course, I do not mean that they are not successful or failed but what should I call them?

Comment: Drawer > pair of underpants as opposed to a sketch artist

Comment: @mplungjan: surely *a* drawer is only underpant-related if you put both legs through one hole.

Comment: So if we have two sketch artists they are a pair of drawers.

Comment: Semantically yes, linguistically no. I'd call them careless, instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The word to use for people who lose things would depend on why they are suspected of losing them. They might be **absent-minded** or **forgetful** as suggested in another answer, but they could also be **disorganized**, **distracted**, or **preoccupied**, for example.

*Loser* is not valid because here "lose" is always understood in the sense of winning and losing a competition. It can be neutral, to describe the loser of an organized game or prize, or to diminish those not at the top in business or society, or disparagingly to call someone hapless or a failure.

The only time it does not is when making a play on words. For example, the television show *The Biggest Loser* features teams of obese people who compete to lose the most weight. The biggest "loser" is thus actually the winner of the competition.

There are numerous other examples in which the obvious noun formed from a verb has a different and stronger primary meaning:

> <del>waiter > one who waits, as for a late train</del>
>
> waiter > one who waits on tables, as in a restaurant
>
> <del>boxer > one who packages things in boxes</del>
>
> boxer > one who fist-fights for sport
>
> <del>skipper > one who skips instead of walks</del>
>
> skipper > the chief officer of a ship

Comment: Sometimes a word that would be formed by a standard rule overlaps a word with a special use so strongly that you can't use the normal rule. You should be able to turn "lose" into "loser" to mean one who loses things, but you can't because the word "loser" (a pathetic person, from the sense of "lose" that means to not win) dominates. It's the same reason you can't call a person from Hamburg, Germany a "Hamburger". The word "hamburger" is too strong.

Comment: As I point out in my answer, this overstates the case. It's not true that *loser* is "always understood in the sense of winning and losing a competition." You can sometimes use it if you specify what the person loses/lost.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't, unless you want to be misunderstood. It will never be taken to mean someone who loses things. You just have to say such a person is forgetful, or absent-minded, or . . . always loses things.

Comment: There are actually quite a few postings on various Internet forums/Q&A sites asking the same as OP. I guess it regularly occurs to people that the "literal" meaning of "loser" has been completely lost, so we no longer have a word to distinguish someone who routinely forgets his wedding anniversary from someone who routinely leaves his house keys down the pub! Not that it really matters, since they're usually the same type of person. I call myself **sieve-brained** - keep the nuggets and let the rubbish wash on through!

Answer (score 6):

It isn't common, but you can, as long as you specify what they lose: *a loser of keys, the loser of those sunglasses,* etc.